# How to use aria-invalid and aria-describedby attributes for checkboxe group

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, accessibility

I have a checkbox set as a form element and need to use aria-invalid and aria-describedby attributes on them. Should the attribute be written on every single checkbox or on a fieldset?

Answer (score 1):

[Tenon](https://tenon.io/) team has researched that case thoroughly and came to the conclusion of not using aria attributes at all since the results in various screen readers are discouraging.

There solution/ suggestion is the next:

> **Dynamically injecting the error text into the legend**.
> Our winning combination came from completely stepping away from the tried and tested aria-describedby and manipulating the legend text based on the current validity state of the control. When an error occurred we appended it to the text in the legend and removed it again if no error condition existed.

Check their [blog post](https://blog.tenon.io/accessible-validation-of-checkbox-and-radiobutton-groups) for more details on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

In general, any object that is in error should have aria-invalid set to true.  Setting that on the fieldset might be a bit confusing.  Does it mean all the objects in the fieldset are in error?  What if some are in error and others are not?  Does that make the fieldset in error?  Or is it partially in error?  Perhaps you have a design where it makes sense to have the fieldset in error, but that is probably an exception rather than the rule.

Technically, from an html spec perspective, it is valid to set `aria-invalid` on a fieldset (https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-fieldset-element).  See "Allowed ARIA state and property attributes".

I am confused, though, by your original question.  You want to set aria-invalid on a checkbox?  How does a checkbox become invalid?  It's either checked or not.  Do you put the user in a scenario where checking the box isn't valid?  If so, shouldn't the checkbox be disabled?

And for `aria-describedby`, you'll want to test that with various browsers and screen readers.  Sometimes the label associated with `aria-describedby` isn't read immediately.  There can be a pause, or the screen might say to hit alt+`<somekey>` to hear the description.  `aria-labelledby`, on the other hand, is read immediately.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a checkbox set as a form element and need to use `aria-invalid` and `aria-describedby` attributes on them. Should the attribute be written on every single checkbox or on a fieldset?

From a theorical point of view, it makes more sense to set it on a `fieldset`.

An individual checkbox has only two states, and I can't see how one individual checkbox within a fieldset could have an error, except when there's only one checkbox (license agreement for instance)

For the same reason if your `aria-describedby` point to the error message, it has to be on the same element.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't set the attributes on all elements but you could set the aria-invalid to true for the first check box only.

Example:

```
<input name="nom" aria-invalid="false"
    onclick="checkValidity('nom', ' ', 'your message 1');">
<br />
<input name="courriel" aria-invalid="false"
    onclick="checkValidity('courriel', '@', 'your second message);">

//js
<script type="text/javascript>
  var checkValidity = function(aID, aMsg){
  var elem = this,
    invalid = (elem.value.indexOf(aSearchTerm) < 0);
  if (invalid) {
   elem.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "true");
   updateAlert(aMsg);
  }  else {
   elem.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "false");
 }
}
</script>
```

OR you can use JQuery

Comment: Linking the information to every control in the group would be terrible for the user. If every control says that it is invalid while the group is invalid it would lead to very verbose repetition for screen reader users while leading to a confusing state in checkbox groups where a selected control can be invalid just because the minimum selected number has not been reached.

Comment: Attempted using the first control in the group for the attachment point for both aria-describedby as well as aria-invalid:

Comment: JAWS/Firefox: When tabbing from link, only the legend and for some reason the page title is heard. Must move between radios (or checkboxes) to hear the error and labels.
    JAWS/IE11: Legend, error and label are read.
    JAWS/Edge: Only the label is read, not the legend or the error.
    JAWS/Chrome: Legend, error and label are read, though repeats somewhat.

Comment: NVDA/Firefox: When navigating from an error link, reads only the unchecked and aria-invalid states. Only moving deliberately into forms mode (tabbing for instance) and back to the first input is the label and error message read (no legend even then).
NVDA/IE11: When navigating from an error link, reads only the unchecked and aria-invalid states. Only moving deliberately into forms mode (tabbing for instance) and back to the first input is the label and error message read (no legend even then).NVDA/Edge: Legend, error and label are read.NVDA/Chrome: Legend, error and label are read.

Comment: VoiceOver/Safari: Legend and label are read twice, error is not read.
VoiceOver/Chrome: Legend, error and label are read.
Narrator/Edge: Label, aria-invalid state, and description is read, but no legend.

Comment: Please check the blog post link on my answer for more details